# Pthread win32 libraray, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED not supported

Tags: winapi, pthreads, posix, mqueue, pthreads-win32

I am using pthread win32 library to implement mqueue. 
But when it runs into following code, it throw #40 error should be ENOSYS, means system not supported.

```
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
i = pthread_mutex_init(&mqhdr->mqh_lock, &mattr);
pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mattr);      /* be sure to destroy */
```

i is 40 after it goes wrong. Any body has idea about this? or do you have some other alternative solution, like use what kind of WIN32 thread function to replace it.

Note: If anyone successfully implement a mqueue in win32?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166316/what-is-the-performance-of-boostinterprocess-mutex-vs-win32-native-mutexes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808617/difference-between-locks-mutex-and-critical-sections

Answer (score 1):

You will want to read up on Windows [interprocess synchronization functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684123%28VS.85%29.aspx).

For an inter-process mutex in Windows, your choices are to implement your own using shared memory and [InterlockedCompareExchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683560%28VS.85%29.aspx) (spin then sleep or watch for [Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682655%28VS.85%29.aspx)).

Or easier to program but not as performant is to use the OS provided named [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411%28VS.85%29.aspx) object. These perform about 10 times worse than using [CriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682608%28VS.85%29.aspx) within threads of a process.

In my own production code I was porting from Linux pthreads, I played with the first solution, but ended up releasing the code using the Mutex solution. It was more reliable and I was sure it would work in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

I recognize the code you are using ...just comment the 2 lines in the code

```
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
pthread_condattr_setpshared(&cattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
```

...it works fine as a intra-process message queue ...unless you need it across processes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you feel comfortable hacking inside the Win32 PThread library, but, while the full PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED behavior cannot be attained, it IS possible to duplicate handles to kernel objects into other processes using the [DuplicateHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724251%28VS.85%29.aspx) API - so it should be possible to add some windows specific extensions (that would compile out in unix builds) that allow a mutex to be shared between processes.

Answer (score 0):

•A child process created by the CreateProcess function can inherit a handle to a mutex object if the lpMutexAttributes parameter of CreateMutex enabled inheritance. This mechanism works for both named and unnamed mutexes.

•A process can specify the handle to a mutex object in a call to the DuplicateHandle function to create a duplicate handle that can be used by another process. This mechanism works for both named and unnamed mutexes.

•A process can specify a named mutex in a call to the OpenMutex or CreateMutex function to retrieve a handle to the mutex object.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is [Aurelio Medina's code from 2000](http://cygwin.com/ml/pthreads-win32/2000/msg00131.html).

Unfortunately, his test code was a single process, so it didn't care if the PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED flag was set or not, since pthreads-32 has never supported it.  When he built it in 2000, I bet that pthreads did't even throw an error, so his test code run fine.

Unfortunately for all of us, it seems he [died in 2013](http://www.legacy.com/obituaries/mercurynews/obituary.aspx?pid=169766473), so he's not going to finish his opus.

I've taken up the torch and rewrote the mutex/signal handling to use native windows mutex and events. Please look here for the code:

**https://github.com/marklakata/mqueue-w32**